# How to use PXSelect to get a user defined field? (AKA the ext fields)

Tags: acumatica

I've added a few fields to the items table. I need to be able to reference those fields from code when the SOLine is updated.

I've got a PXSelect that works correctly, and gets me an InventoryItem, but clearly I need to be in the Ext section (AKA, return an InventoryItemExt) but I'm not clear how I make PXSelect do that.

This returns the item I need:

```
      InventoryItem iiTheItem = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, row.InventoryID);
```

But Fails here:

```
dQPI = Convert.ToDecimal(iiTheItemExt.UsrLbsPerInch);
```

If I make a variable as the ext it works syntax wise but obviously loads nothing.

```
InventoryItemExt iiTheItemExt = null;
dQPI = Convert.ToDecimal(iiTheItemExt.UsrLbsPerInch);
```

How to I bridge the PXSelect and the class I need? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a code example that retrieves an InventoryItem based on a specified criteria, returns it and then accesses its declared extension.

```
            InventoryItemExtension itemExt;
            InventoryItem item = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>.Select(this.Base, new object[] { "TEST" });
            if(item != null)
            {
                itemExt = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<InventoryItemExtension>(item);
                decimal? dQPI = Convert.ToDecimal(itemExt.UsrLbsPerInch);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

PXSelect is fine as is. You need to call the GetExtension method with the Base DAC record to obtain a reference to the DAC extension.

Here are some usage examples:

```
InventoryItemExt iiTheItemExt = iiTheItem.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();
InventoryItemExt iiTheItemExt = Base.Caches[typeof(InventoryItem)].GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(iiTheItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your extension is called InventoryItemExt...

```
 InventoryItemExt itemext = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(iiTheItem );
```